# Is UIImageView with UIViewContentModeCenter smart about anti-aliasing?

Tags: ios

This may be wishful thinking, but is iOS smart enough to avoid blurring my image when it's positioning is handled by UIViewContentModeCenter?

I need the image contained within my UIImageView to be centered within a certain area. The easiest way I could think of  is to make my imageView the size of this area and then to set UIViewContentModeCenter. I'm usually careful to set my image positions to whole numbers to avoid blurring due to anti-aliasing.

```
CGRect centeredInArea = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 30.0f);
myImageView.frame = centeredInArea;
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Comment: Have you actually tried the above to see if it's a good solution for what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

When a UIImageView is drawn I believe the context's `CGContextGetInterpolationQuality` is set to `kCGInterpolationDefault`. I don't think you can change this but `CGContext` supports other quality levels that provide other quality levels. [Here](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) is an example of better image scaling by setting the quality higher. I believe this would also help when centering images.

Also you can color misaligned images in the iOS simulator which can help when figuring out if images are already centered properly.